# Dynamic menu in shinydashboard with conditionalPanel

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

**Background**

I am trying to develop an app, which has a login screen and shows different menus depending on the user's rights.

The user rights are hierarchical, meaning that an `Read + Write` user should have the same rights as a `Read` user plus some additional rights.

I am struggling now how to create this dynamic menu. I read [this document on dynamic UIs](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/dynamic-ui.html) and I hoped I could achieve my goal purely with the use of `conditionalPanel` calls.

In the code below, you see that there is a lot of duplication. And worst of all, I have to assign unique names to the `tabs` even if they are in different (mutual exclusive) panels (`a1` and `a2`) but which are meant to do exactly the same.

**Things tried so far**

I tried to move the `conditionalPanel` into `sidebarMenu` (and `tabItems` respectively), but then I get an error, because the return type of `conditionalPanel` does not match the expected type.

**Expected Outcome**

Finally, I want to have minimal duplication of code. That is, I want to define the UI for `Do A` and `Do B` exactly *once*, but *re-use* `Do A` for both users.

Which options do I have? Do I have to fall back to dynamic rendering (`renderUI` / `renderMenu`) or is there a way how I can achieve the desired behavior w/ `conditionalPanel` only?

**Working Code with Duplication**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
   dashboardHeader(),
   dashboardSidebar(
      selectInput("userrights", label = "User Rights:", 
                   choices = c("Read + Write", "Read")),
      conditionalPanel("input.userrights == 'Read'",
                       sidebarMenu(
                          menuItem("Do A", tabName = "a1")
                       )
      ),
      conditionalPanel("input.userrights == 'Read + Write'",
                       sidebarMenu(
                          ## unnecessary duplication + I need yet another tab 'a2'
                          menuItem("Do A", tabName = "a2"),
                          menuItem("Do B", tabName = "b2")
                       )
      )
   ),
   dashboardBody(
      conditionalPanel("input.userrights == 'Read'",
                       tabItems(
                          tabItem("a1", h1("A was done"))
                       )
      ),
      conditionalPanel("input.userrights == 'Read + Write'",
                       tabItems(
                          tabItem("a2", h1("A was done")),
                          tabItem("b2", h1("B was done"))
                       )
      )
   )
)

server <- function(input, output) {}

runApp(shinyApp(ui, server))
```

**Snippet: Not working but at least w/o Duplication**

```
sidebarMenu(
   menuItem("Do A", tabName = "a")
   conditionalPanel("input.userrights == 'Read + Write'",
      menuItem("Do B", tabName = "b")
   )
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can render your menu in the server based on user input or other conditions, and output that to the UI. Working example below:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    selectInput("userrights", label = "User Rights:", 
                choices = c("Read + Write", "Read")),
    sidebarMenuOutput("menu")
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem("a", h1("A was done")),
      tabItem("b", h1("B was done"))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {


  output$menu <- renderMenu({

    my_list = list(menuItem("a", tabName="a"))

    if(input$userrights=="Read + Write")
       my_list[[2]] = menuItem("b", tabName="b")

    sidebarMenu(my_list)

  })

}

runApp(shinyApp(ui, server))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer +1. So as assumed the best way is to fall back to `renderMenu`?